# Clustered Bar plot in r using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Snip of my data frame is

[image]

Basically i want to display barplot which is grouped by Country i.e i want to display no of people doing suicides for all of the country in clustered plot and similarly for accidents and Stabbing as well.I am using ggplot2 for this.I have no idea how to do this.

Any helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For future reference, posting an image of your data is about the least useful method of displaying it here. Look at how to make a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example - you'll get much more help if you make your data easy to use

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit to update for newer (2017) package versions**

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat.g <- gather(dat, type, value, -country)
ggplot(dat.g, aes(type, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = country), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

### [image]

**Original Answer**

```
dat <- data.frame(country=c('USA','Brazil','Ghana','England','Australia'), Stabbing=c(15,10,9,6,7), Accidents=c(20,25,21,28,15), Suicide=c(3,10,7,8,6))
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars='country')
```

I guess this is the format you're after?

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = country), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: `library(reshape)`

Comment: @Hack-R check to be sure you are not trying to plot a factor.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(country=c('USA','Brazil','Ghana','England','Australia'), Stabbing=c(15,10,9,6,7), Accidents=c(20,25,21,28,15), Suicide=c(3,10,7,8,6))
mm <- melt(df, id.vars='country')
ggplot(mm, aes(x=country, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_grid(.~variable) + coord_flip() + labs(x='',y='')
```

[image]